# What technology or framework should I use to build something like this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, frontend

[image]

See pic. Basically, when the user clicks on the buttons on the Home page, the corresponding page will be shown. However, I want it to load without refreshing the entire browser window. I think this is called Ajax right?

If so, where should I get started with this? What frameworks should I use which will be easiest to do and setup? All I need is to load pages in this manner, nothing fancy or extra.

Tks!

Comment: Take a look at jQuery, particularly `.get()`, `.post()`, `.ajax()`, and `.load()`

Comment: Angular is best option, check these links to get started!
http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/
http://www.toptal.com/angular-js/a-step-by-step-guide-to-your-first-angularjs-app

Comment: Angular is not the best option. It is limited in comparison to react.

Comment: Just keep in mind that with jQuery, one line of code `$("#content").load(url)` is all you need to load some content into a `div` on your page.  Hook that up to a click event handler and you're practically done.   So, a Single Page Application framework is definitely not needed at all for what you're trying to do.  Just load jQuery in your page and hook up each button to an appropriate click event handler.

Comment: Whats the content within the pages? If you dont need any magic within these pages, i don't think you need to get in touch with MVC frameworks just to achieve a simple 3 submenued homepage, unless you want to ;) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think this is called Ajax right

Single Page Application (SPA for short).

> What frameworks should I use which will be easiest to do and setup

Popular:

- React (my preference for something simple like you want)
- Angular
- Ember

Or roll your own. Or pick one from : [google search](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=spa%20framework)

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is called Single-Page-Application (SPA).
Ajax comes into when you wan't to retrieve or send data from or to a backend.

If you are looking for bigger frameworks **emberjs** or **angular** are popular and solid frameworks for buiding one-page-applications.

A smaller framework, whose learning curve is a lot faster would be **backbone**.

If you want to have the technologie stack very simple you could also just use **jquery** in combination with a template engine like **handlebars**.

It all depends on how complex your application will become.

Take a look at some comparision papers like these

https://www.airpair.com/js/javascript-framework-comparison or https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/beginners-angular-ember-backbone

They will help you to choose the right framework for your needs.